# Problem with importing remote users from the CSV file

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a problem with importing remote users from the CSV file.

Export is working perfectly using the following command:

```
Get-LocalGroupMember -Group "Remote Desktop Users" | select Name | Export-csv -path "C:\Users\username\Desktop\rdpusers\GroupMembers.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

I get a CSV file which looks like this:

```
"Name"
"DOMAIN\username1"
"DOMAIN\username2"
"DOMAIN\username3"
```

When i try importing the CSV file using the following command:

```
Import-csv -Path "C:\Users\username\Desktop\rdpusers\GroupMembers.csv"  ForEach-Object {Add-LocalGroupMember-Group "Remote Desktop Users" -Member $_.'Name'}
```

I get the next error:

```
Import-Csv : Cannot bind parameter 'Delimiter'. Cannot convert value "ForEach-Object" to type "System.Char". Error: "String must be exactly one character long."
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like you forgot a `|` just before `ForEach-Object`

Comment: Oh God, thank you so much! You are a lifesaver. :)

Answer (score 0):

Two things were missing from my Import command.

A pipe before ForEach-Object, and a space before -Group

```
Import-csv -Path "C:\Users\djerkovic\Desktop\rdpusers\GroupMembers.csv" | ForEach-Object {Add-LocalGroupMember -Group "Remote Desktop Users" -Member $_.'Name'}
```

Thank you to Mathias R. Jessen for his kind help. :)